# How to create a simple debugging IDE for .NET

Tags: .net, debugging, clr

I'm looking for options in .NET to be able to step through compiled code and stop at a breakpoint. Sort of like a simplified visual studio.

My application uses a plugin system using CodeDom.Compiler which is working well and its the plugin code that I want the end users to be able to debug. The javascript front end uses codemirror for editing the files (browser communicates with the .NET instance via websockets). I'd like to extend this integrated code management functionality to allow the end users to do simple debugging like breaking on a line (set in codemirror), view variables and step into code.

I'm not sure the most direct way to do this. I have looked at stacktrace but that is more appropriate for exception management. Either some form of logging function or hooking into the low level debugging interfaces in the CLR which I assume is how VS works.

Does anyone have any pointers which direction I could explore for such a solution?

(yes, I'm aware I'm duplicating functionality in VS but I want an integrated solution). Thanks!

Comment: Use the [mdbg sample](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2282) as a starting point for implementing your own debugger.  Do keep in mind that a program cannot debug itself, a debugger must run in its own process.

Comment: Thanks Hans, looking at it now.